# About TDengine SQL

Tags: sql, tdengine

I use the TDengine RESTful connector to query SQL statements in my springboot project, but I cannot understand the content in the metadata. What do the two parameters after the column name mean in "column_meta"?
mysql:

```
select * from test.testtable
```

result:

```
"status":"succ","head":["ts","col1"],"column_meta":[["ts",9,8],["col1",10,8]],"data":[["2021-10-26 06:18:43.318","4"],["2021-10-26 06:18:50.601","1"],["2021-10-26 06:18:54.666","2"],["2021-10-26 06:18:58.227","3"]],"rows":4
```

Answer (score 0):

`"column_meta":[["ts",9,8],["col1",10,8]]`
`ts` means your first column name.
`9`  is the datatype, which is timestamp.
`8` is the size of data.
and so on...